# Advantage of bst representations using arrays

Tags: binary-search-tree

The representation of a bst using arrays I always used is a sorted array with its root in the middle, and each child being halfway through the endpoints of the array and the root

The other day I came across a different representation: the root is the first element of the array (index 0). Then, for an element with index n, 2n+1 is its left child, and 2n + 2 its right child

My question is what advantages does the latter offer? They're both balanced trees, so we're assured log n search complexity. However, the first representation looks like it's better for insertion/deletion since for both representations that requires moving a lot of elements in the tree, and it seems naturally easier (for me) to do so with the first representation

Search by range also sounds nicer in the first representation since elements are contiguous

Is there any situation in which I should use the second representation? (provided, of course, that I choose to use an array representation)

Answer (score 2):

One that immediately comes to mind is that, if you’ll be accessing the left and right children in quick succession, the latter implementation gives you better locality of reference.

That is, if the children are stored far apart in a big array, they’ll be in different pages of memory, and therefore accesses to both are likely to be cache misses or even page faults. In the layout that puts both children in consecutive locations, almost all accesses to the second child will be in the cache. This could have a big effect on the speed of breadth-first searches.

The former implementation produces a sorted array, which can speed up many other algorithms.

The latter adds new children at the end of the array, so if the algorithm fills out each layer of a balanced tree, the second layout does not require any nodes to be moved or swapped.

Comment: It's true, parents are much easier to find. But there isn't much besides that right?

Comment: Parents are very easy to find in the second case: `(i-1)>>1`. But I was thinking of something else: if the children are stored far apart in a big array, they’ll be in different pages of memory, and therefore successive accesses are likely to be cache misses or even page faults. In the layout that puts both children in consecutive locations, almost all accesses to the second child will be in the cache. This could have a big effect on the speed of breadth-first and depth-first searches.